# Installed banner slider in magento 2, but nothing works

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

After referring to the installation guides, I have installed banner slider extension using ftp, but as I run the command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it doesn't show any process, and it takes me to the root folder to enter another command.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Which extension did you install?
Please run the cache clean, upgrade, and deploy commands

I recommend you use the [megplaza banner slider extension](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-banner-slider-extension/) instead. This is free of cost and [full documentation](https://docs.mageplaza.com/banner-slider-m2/) is available.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used the same slider but the issue is when I run the command in putty nothing works. no process is there...

Comment: check path for magneto installed directory .